# Play Framework SSE Closing Chunked Response

Tags: java, playframework, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement *Server-Side Events* server in *Play Framework 1.2.5*

How can I know if the client called `EventSource.close()` (or closed its browser window, for example)? This is a simplified piece of server code I'm using:

```
public class SSE extends Controller {

  public static void updater() {
    response.contentType = "text/event-stream";
    response.encoding = "UTF-8";
    response.status = 200;
    response.chunked = true;

    while (true) {
      Promise<String> promise = Producer.getNextMessage();
      String msg = await(promise);
      response.writeChunk("data: " + msg + "\n\n");
    }
  }
}
```

`Producer` should deal with queuing, `Promise` objects, and produce the output, but I should know when to stop it (filling its queue). I would expect some exception thrown by `response.writeChunk()` if the output stream is closed, but there's no any.

There's a similar example that does not deal with SSE, but only chunks instead, at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/asynchronous#HTTPresponsestreaming

Answer (score 0):

Since `play.mvc.Controller` doesn't let me know if the output stream is closed during the execution, I solved the problem through the `Producer` itself:

1. In `Producer.getNextMessage()`, the current time is remembered.
2. In `Producer.putMessage(String)`, the time since last 'get' is checked. If it's greater than some threshold, we can consider that SSE channel is closed.

There's also this class `play.libs.F.EventStream` which can be useful within the `Producer`.

Plus, `Producer` might not be the right name here, since it's more of a dispatching queue...